# Spring AOP Aspect advice with method parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an aspect advice like following

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* de.ojk.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService.getAttribute(..))")
public void fixUrl()
....
```

getAttribute method accepts only one String parameter.

what I would like to do, I want "fixUrl" to be executed only when 'name' string is given as parameter. "getAttribute('name')". How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* de.ojk.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService.getAttribute(..)) && args(String)")
public void after1(JoinPoint jp){
    System.out.println(jp.getArgs()[0]);
    System.out.println("after Return:"+jp.getSignature());
}
```

Above Way Can work. If you want support other type except String  ,change String to what you want . jp.getArgs()[0] get the variable!
The below Way you can try  , i try it successfully in my code!

```
 @AfterReturning(value = "execution(@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* de.ojk.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService.getAttribute(..)) && args(a)")
public void after2(JoinPoint jp,String a){
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println("after Return:"+jp.getSignature());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am looking for something inside annotation to give method value. I mean, I don't want to if/else inside method body. Method will be executed only if this specific has been passed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible. Method pointcut expressions are powerful in distinguishing which methods to join or exclude, based on signature and context. The values of the arguments themselves are outside that scope.

In any case, I'd argue there's an advantage to putting the conditional check in your code. It's more resistant to breakage from refactoring, particularly if you make the value you're checking for a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your aspect code:

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* de.ojk.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService.getAttribute(..))")
    public void fixUrl(JoinPoint p){
        String name;
        Object[] signatureArgs = p.getArgs();
        if (signatureArgs.length > 0) {
            Class baseRequestClass = signatureArgs[0].getClass();
            try {
                Method requestIdMethod = baseRequestClass.getMethod("name");
                name = requestIdMethod.invoke(signatureArgs[0]) != null
                        ? requestIdMethod.invoke(signatureArgs[0]).toString() : null;

                if (name != null) {
                    System.out.println("Provided Name :" + name);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No Name parameter provided");
                }

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here name has value that is provided. If null then not provided. I added the 
log, is there name has or not.

**Here is your imports**:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
```